# Выбрать N случайных строк из файла общедоступными инструментами *nix

Tags: php, linux, bash, unix, reservoirsampling

Файл текстовый, UTF-8, 500 тысяч строк, длинной от 5 до 185 байт каждая.

Интересует в первую очередь оптимальное по времени решение.

Под *общедоступными* должно понимать инструменты, которые можно найти на **любом** *nix VDS из коробки, включая Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD и так далее.

Сейчас используется PHP и время устраивает, но бытует мнение, что можно быстрее:

```
<?php
function sample (array $data, int $n) : array {
    $results = [];
    $last = count ($data) - 1;
    while (count ($results) < $n)
        if ( ! isset ($result [$r = $data [rand (0, $last)]]))
            $results [$r] = TRUE;
    return array_keys ($results);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что мерить скорость загрузки данных в память не нужно.

Comment: `$ shuf -n количество файл`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ответом? )

Comment: @Suvitruf, это же не ответ: программа *shuf* никаким боком не входит в «стандартные инструменты \*nix». «стандартными» же «интсрументами» решение будет *очень* громоздким, и придумывать его нет никакого желания. помимо прочего сама формулировка вопроса («оптимальное по времени решение») уже подразумевает, что вопрос надо бы закрывать как слишком общий: требуется сравнить **несколько** решений и обосновать выбор «оптимального по времени» (что бы это ни значило).

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, все верно именно это и требуется. зачем закрывать вопрос не понятно. не нравится, просто проходите мимо.

Comment: @leninel так а нет же голосов за закрытие

Comment: Можно ли "стандартными средствами" выполнить [reservoir sampling](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)?

Comment: По вашей ссылке цитата: "Обычно, n достаточно велико, чтобы весь список не уместился в основной памяти.". У нас как раз случай когда все в памяти поместится точно. Нужно быстро.

Comment: @leninel, так оно от этого медленнее не становится.

Comment: Взял на себя наглость убрать «стандартные» из вопроса, так как стандарты в мире *nix очень широко трактуются. Например, sed под macOS (которая официальный Unix) совсем не тот же sed что под Linux. И так далее и тому подобное.

Comment: @sanmai [а вот додумывать за автора не стоит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/998829/revisions#rev-arrow-038da102-c253-4beb-a427-708f95d1a2bd)

Comment: @sanmai да и brew, кстати, совершенно не является «штатной утилитой»

Comment: @andreymal `brew` это фактический стандарт для установки софта под macOS, о чем вы говорите? "штатнее" ничего другого нет; кстати даже `sort` под macOS не та же самая, как и, впрочем, под другими *BDS.

Comment: @andreymal давайте и не загонять исходный вопрос в жесткие рамки ограниченного мышления автора, мы тут общественное дело делаем, а не какому-то одному человеку помогаем что-то решить (такие, другие, вопросы вообще оффтопик)

Comment: @sanmai можете создать отдельный вопрос, описав в нём желаемые вами критерии и сделав в нём общественное дело ;)

Comment: @sanmai brew отсутствует в изкоробочной поставке macOS, а Apple не предоставляет никакого официального способа его установки (потому что brew не имеет вообще никакого отношения к Apple), и ваши рассуждения о «фактическом стандарте» — это лишь ваши личные рассуждения и не более того. То, что каждый первый продвинутый пользователь macOS первым делом ставит brew, не делает его «штатной утилитой». Кроме того, может быть так, что автору нужна работоспособность решения условиях отсутствия интернета и запрета подключения внешних устройств хранения данных, где ни о brew, ни о apt речь идти не может

Comment: также можно и про rpm, pip как о brew говорить.  brew - это сторонняя утилита

Comment: @andreymal это теперь вы за автора додумываете

Comment: @sanmai поэтому я и не делаю соответствующих правок ;) Сказано из коробки — значит из коробки, а про apt и brew додумывать не надо)

Comment: Эм, пхп есть далеко не на любом *nix VDS... Описанные в вопросе условия теперь просто противоречат друг другу

Comment: @sanmai у вас сегодня прям день додумываний какой-то: то про MIT, то про плашку, теперь вот про то, что нет других *никсов кроме линукса

Comment: @andreymal другие варианты есть, но автор судя по всему (как вы сами заметили) не понимает того зоопарка, который есть в мире *nix, потому даёт противоречивые требования.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

можно использовать `sort -R input | head -n N`, но скорость работы будет значительнее ниже, чем того же shuf ,но лучше сравнить результаты.

На моем ноутбуке с SSD дискоим, 16 Гб ОЗУ 2133 MHz, Intel Core i7-7700HQ  2,8 GHz слудующие результаты:

У меня есть файл размером 2.6G и с 13,9 млн строк данных

```
➜  /tmp wc -l test.log
 13904430 test.log

➜  /tmp time awk 'rand() <0.001' < test.log |wc
   13945   32795 2774781
awk 'rand() <0.001' < test.log  124.15s user 1.18s system 99% cpu 2:05.68 total
wc  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2:05.68 total


➜  /tmp time sort -R test.log | head -n 10000 >/dev/null
^C^C (тут я не дождался и отменил процесс)
sort -R test.log  751.22s user 72.00s system 54% cpu 25:02.76 total
head -n 10000 > /dev/null  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 25:01.63 total


➜  /tmp time shuf -n 10000 test.log |wc
   10000   23637 1986699
shuf -n 10000 test.log  4.59s user 0.66s system 98% cpu 5.326 total
wc  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 5.325 total

 ➜  /tmp time perl -ne 'print if (rand() < 0.001)' test.log | wc
   13872   32644 2755088
perl -ne 'print if (rand() < 0.001)' test.log  1.74s user 0.70s system 99% cpu 2.454 total
wc  0.01s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.453 total
```

также написал ради эксперимента вот такую функцию, но не дождался результата больше 20 минут

```
➜  /tmp function rread() { while read line; do
    if ((RANDOM%1390)); then
        echo $line;
    fi;
done < $1  }
➜  /tmp time rread test.log > /dev/null
```

итоговый результат таков:

1. perl за 2.453
2. shuf за 5.325
3. awk  за 2:05.68
4. sort -R больше, чем 25:01.63
5. read думаю больше, чем в 4 пункте

p.s. 
также решил пропробовать через sed выдернуть строку. 
написал вот такой скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash

RANGE=$(wc -l < $2)
for i in `seq 1 $1`
{
  number=$(echo $RANDOM % $RANGE + 1 | bc)
  sed -n ''${number}'p' $2 
}
```

результат удручающий

```
➜  /tmp time ./custom.sh 10 test.log | wc
      10      22    1567
./custom.sh 10 test.log  35.91s user 6.76s system 99% cpu 42.872 total
wc  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 42.871 total

➜  /tmp time ./custom.sh 100 test.log | wc
     100     197   16407
./custom.sh 100 test.log  362.07s user 70.14s system 99% cpu 7:15.37 total
wc  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 7:15.37 total
```

**UPDATE**

```
cat <<'EOT' >> p.php 
<?php
ini_set ('memory_limit', '8192M');
$t0 = microtime (TRUE);
$file = 'data.txt';
$data = (is_file ($file) and is_readable ($file)) ? file ($file) : [];
$t1 = microtime (TRUE);
const LIMIT = 10;
$results = [];
$last = count ($data) - 1;
while (count ($results) < LIMIT) if ( ! isset ($result [$r = $data [rand (0, $last)]])) $results [$r] = TRUE;
$results = array_keys ($results);
$t2 = microtime (TRUE);
printf ("%s, %s", number_format ($t1 - $t0, 8), number_format ($t2 - $t1, 8));

?>
EOT
➜ php -f p.php
12.23668194, 0.00460792
```

хочу заметить, что весь процесс от запуска и до завершения скрипта больше на 2-3 секунды. Я думаю, было бы правильно и это время учитывать.

**UPDATE2**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


unsigned int rand_interval(unsigned int min, unsigned int max);

int main(){
 ifstream is("test.log");

 char c;
 string line;
 int count=13000;
 while (!is.eof() && count-->0){
  while (c != '\n'){
   unsigned int rand = rand_interval(0, 13900000);
   is.seekg(rand);
   c = is.get();
  }
  getline(is,line);
  cout << line << endl;
  c = '0';
 }


 return 0;
}

unsigned int rand_interval(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
    int r;
    const unsigned int range = 1 + max - min;
    const unsigned int buckets = RAND_MAX / range;
    const unsigned int limit = buckets * range;
    do
    {
        r = rand();
    } while (r >= limit);

    return min + (r / buckets);
}
```

и результат

```
➜  /tmp time ./a.out | wc
   13000   29103 2209950
./a.out  4.54s user 7.00s system 98% cpu 11.672 total
wc  0.02s user 0.07s system 0% cpu 11.671 total
```

Comment: У решений в духе `rand() <0.001` есть два косяка: во-первых, они неточные, а во-вторых, в них заложено знание пользователя о числе строк. У честных решений надо сначала посчитать число строк и будет два чтения файла, так что они будут примерно вдвое медленнее. В принципе, `shuf` примерно такой результат и показал.

Comment: да, ты прав. я примерно апроксимировал результат к 13.9к. shuf, конечно же рвет в простоте использования и в быстроте работы

Comment: А вообще, к вопросу в комментарии ссылку на алгоритмы добавили - один проход при неизвестной длине.

Comment: а вы не могли бы померить пхп скрипт из первого поста на своих данных?

Comment: @leninel я не знаю php. я не понимаю как мне скормить файл. если поможете, то я запущу проверку

Comment: смотрите первый пост

Comment: @leninel обновил.

Comment: если несколько раз подряд запускать, то время уменьшается и постепенно стремится к 6.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы уверены, что 50Мб файл во второй раз будет читаться примерно за то же время, что и в первый?

Comment: @avp, не знаю. Думаешь, в кэше диска останется? Но в ответе на 2.6 ГБ проверяли.

Comment: @Qwertiy, 2ГБ может и не останется, но в вопросе вроде речь о ~50M (*`"500 тысяч строк, длинной от 5 до 185 байт каждая"`*)

Answer (score 2):

```
shuf file.txt -n5
```

file.txt - ваш файл

5 - количество строк(любое число)

[Описание команды на сайте GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html) (к вопросу о "стандартности")

Comment: К вопросу о «стандартности» в macOS никакого GNU не завезли, например :)

Comment: Потому ни о какой «стандартности» говорит не приходится. Нет её.